# Firestore 1 write per second limit error in transaction

Tags: error-handling, transactions, google-cloud-firestore

If i have a transaction on 2 docs: A and B and in doc A is possibile to incur in 1 write per second limit, in this case: does the transaction fail?

I don't care that the doc A has a not accurate value I want that the doc B (that it's a create document action) doesn't fail, is it so?

I tried 'some manual tests' and look like that the transaction not fail, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit on document write throughput in Firestore is not hard-coded or enforced by any software. It is literally the physical limit of the hardware (or physics) due to the distributed nature of the database, and the consistency guarantees it offers.

A simple test is unlikely to trigger any problematic behavior. If you do more writes than can be committed, they will just queue up and be committed when there is bandwidth/space. So while you may see a delay, you typically won't see an error.

The only case where I can imagine seeing errors is if a queue somewhere overflows. There's no specific way to handle this, as it'll most likely surface as a memory/buffer overflow, or some sort of time-out.